# Set height of container class to height of image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the container class `.external-link` to be the height of the image, and no higher or lower.

```
<p class="external-link"><img src="http://www.vernmccraylaw.com/files/stacks_image_1241.jpg" alt="img_58c1b29bb1309"><strong>Related Articles</strong>Some text’n’stuff for yo clickage.</p>


.external-link {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid $grey;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

.external-link img {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.external-link strong {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
}
```

I know the solution should be simple, I'm just drawing a blank.

JSFIDDLE: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/2rh0ugbz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `height` from `.external-link` and add `overflow: auto` to clear the `float` on the `img`.

```css
.external-link {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid $grey;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  overflow: auto;
}

.external-link img {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.external-link strong {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
}
```

```html
<p class="external-link"><img src="http://www.vernmccraylaw.com/files/stacks_image_1241.jpg" alt="img_58c1b29bb1309"><strong>Related Articles</strong>Some text’n’stuff for yo clickage.</p>
```

Comment: That `overflow: auto` is what I was forgetting. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt np! There are many "clearfix" techniques you might check out. That's probably the simplest one, but it doesn't always work if, say, you intentionally want content to overflow that parent for some reason.